# which is the best way to handle Get-WinEvent exception in case No events are found

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am working on an application which reads events from the event log periodically using polling based scheme. I am using Get-WinEvent command to read the events by calling this powershell command using C# code.

This API throws exception in case no events are returned that match the filters specified as args to this powershell command

Exception -> Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.

Now i am facing problem in differentiate between following 2 situations

1. There are some events in log, My filtering params were wrong, Command failed with the exception
2. Filters are correct, but there are actually no events to return, so API failed with exception

In both cases exception seems to be same.

is there any way to catch the specific exception for case 2, so that i can safely ignore it and for rest of the cases where there can be issue in the filter query, i can handle them properly ??

one way i was thinking was based on Exception message, but they also looks to be same for both.

i want to do something like

```
try
{
//Execute
}
catch(ExceptionOfType2 ex)
{
//ignore
}
catch(OtherException ex)
{
//Log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or above, then you can use the [EventLogQuery class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery.aspx) and related APIs

```
public static EventRecord GetEventRecord(string eventFile, int eventID)
{
  string sQuery = string.Format("*[System/EventID={0}]", eventID);
  EventLogQuery query = new EventLogQuery(eventFile, PathType.FilePath, sQuery);
  EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(query);
  return reader.ReadEvent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a polled process, and you expect that there may not be any events written since the last poll, why not use Get-WinEvent -ListLog to first determine if the log has been written to since the last poll.  Then you can just run the query when you know there should be new records there to return.